# Create 3 empty vertical boxes using CSS

Tags: html, css

Below what I want to achieve:

[image: Box]

How can I do that?

I tried this but in that I have to pass `&nbsp;` and still can't get what I want:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid black;width:150px;height:50px;padding:20px;"></span>
```

I have to pass `&nbsp;` but can't get what in image?

Comment: sorry for inappropriate tag @nerdlyist it has been removed.

Comment: your code does create a box.  Could you be more specific on what is the problem?  Better yet, could you create a fiddle to show what you've tried?

Comment: @LGSon I accepted the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is using a table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
      .box {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
      }
      .spacer {
        width: 50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>(i)</td>
        <td>Single purchaser/beneficiary</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="box">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>(ii)</td>
        <td>Multiple purchasers/beneficiaries</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="box">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>(iii)</td>
        <td>Married couple</td>
        <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="box">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/arrwSwpxV70cO0cH53QZ

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
display:inline-block
```

to

```
display:block
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hmgpgzdv/

Answer (score 0):

Try use a `table` like this:

```css
.box {
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <td>(i)</td>
    <td>Single</td>
    <td class="box"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>(ii)</td>
    <td>multiple</td>
    <td class="box"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>(iii)</td>
    <td>married</td>
    <td class="box"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/gna69zyn/2/).